stdcall calling convention error in CMake script with Clang compiling boost
I am trying to compile the boost library with CMake and Clang on a Window host with a Unix x86_64 target and am receiving these errors:
In file included from ..\src\synchronized_pool_resource.cpp:14:
..\include\boost/container/detail/thread_mutex.hpp:109:39: error: '__stdcall' calling convention is not supported for this target
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall InitializeCriticalSection(::_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *);
                                      ^
..\include\boost/container/detail/thread_mutex.hpp:111:39: error: '__stdcall' calling convention is not supported for this target
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall EnterCriticalSection(::_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *);
                                      ^
..\include\boost/container/detail/thread_mutex.hpp:112:39: error: '__stdcall' calling convention is not supported for this target
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall LeaveCriticalSection(::_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *);
                                      ^
..\include\boost/container/detail/thread_mutex.hpp:113:39: error: '__stdcall' calling convention is not supported for this target
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall DeleteCriticalSection(::_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *);

Also here are the flags I am using:
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi")

I was curious if there was a way to mask these errors somehow or some configuration setting I could add to my CMakeLists file or any general tips on solving this issue. I should also mention I am using vcpkg as a package manager for boost which is potentially causing more complications to this process.
Thanks in advance.
